# BCrypt rawPassword cannot be null Spring

Tags: java, spring, authentication, passwords, bcrypt

I have following problem :

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
> status=500). rawPassword cannot be null
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rawPassword cannot be null

This is my SecurityConfig class

```
package my.taco.web;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/design","/orders").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/","/**").access("permitAll")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/design",true)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");


    }

}
```

also code when i use passwordencoder

```
public User toUser(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder){
        return new User(
                username,passwordEncoder.encode(password),
                fullname,street,city,state,zip,phone);
    }


@PostMapping
    public String processRegistration(RegistrationForm form){
        userRepo.save(form.toUser(passwordEncoder));
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
```

Comment: Check password value, from where it is coming?

Comment: You can not encrypt null values. The error is “As expected”.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had the same problem, and I tried many problems.
At `RegistrationForm.java` file, I declared two constructor, one is with args, the other ones no arg. When I delete the no arg constructor, the form's fields are not null.